# Trying to access single document from Firestore in Typescript and pass it to HTML

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to access a single document in my Firestore (the one who has message "b").  I'm able to find the correct document and print it to the console log, but when I try assigning it to a public variable, one which will be accessed in HTML as default values for the table, the console tells me the variable is undefined, and or that it can't be set to doc.data() contents.

I've tried using the where() function, as well as mergemap() but I'm getting errors in my code editor (for mergemap--Property 'mergeMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>').  I've also tried looping through items (which holds all the documents and I AM able to access in my HTML) but I can't figure out a way to get the length of the Observable.  I've also tried changing the type of defaultdoc to no avail.

Here's what I've got so far

```js
  public defaultdoc: Array<any>;
  public items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(private data: DataService, private fb: FormBuilder, private afs: AngularFirestore) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      message:['', Validators.required]
    })
    //this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);
    let inputString = "b";
    const collection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item> = this.afs.collection('postreply');
    this.items = this.afs.collection('postreply').valueChanges();
    this.afs.collection("postreply").get().toPromise().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
          //console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
          console.log(doc.data().message)
          if(doc.data().message == inputString){
            this.defaultdoc.push(doc.data());
            console.log(this.defaultdoc)
          }

      });
  });

    console.log(this.defaultdoc)
  }
```

Here's the HTML

```
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName = message value = {{defaultdoc.message}}/></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName = title value = {{defaultdoc.title}}/></td>
```

The default values should appear in the two table rows created in the HTML.

Comment: If you get an error, edit your question to include the exact message and stack trace of that error please.

Answer (score 0):

I think your "this" is not pointing out the variable you are using in HTML.
Try using self like this:

```
    public defaultdoc: Array<any>;
  public items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(private data: DataService, private fb: FormBuilder, private afs: AngularFirestore) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      message:['', Validators.required]
    })
    //this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);
    let inputString = "b";
    const collection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item> = this.afs.collection('postreply');
    this.items = this.afs.collection('postreply').valueChanges();
    let self = this;
    this.afs.collection("postreply").get().toPromise().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
          //console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
          console.log(doc.data().message)
          if(doc.data().message == inputString){
            self.defaultdoc.push(doc.data());
            console.log(self.defaultdoc)
          }

      });
  });

    console.log(this.defaultdoc)
  }
```

Hope it works!